# How to convert escape sequences to their appropriate characters in SML?

Tags: escaping, sml

I'm writing an SML program and I'm trying to convert a string that has escape sequences into a string that does not have escape sequences.

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work (prints just `"Hello "`)

```
fun test x  =
let val esc = "Hello \\  Bob \n Newman"
    val fixed = String.fromString esc
in
    print (valOf(fixed))
end
```

I think I might have to use the `String.scan` function however, I don't exactly understand how it works.

The function signature is

```
scan       : (char, 'a) StringCvt.reader
                   -> (string, 'a) StringCvt.reader
```

So I have a few questions:

1) Can you expalin what exactly this scan signature is saying...What arguments does the function take and what does it return

2) Is this the function that I should be using?

3) Can you give me any guidance on using this function.  Thanks

EDIT: Ok, so the above example I simplified, but I may have simplified it too much...Here's exactly what I'm doing.  I'm have a global string called `str` and and input stream of chars/strings...As I read the input stream, I concatenate `str` with the character that I just read.  After I have read all of the characters, I want to return `str` but with all of the escape sequences converted.

Comment: What are you expecting/trying to get as your result?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with functional programming itself.

Comment: What do you mean by converting to a "string that does not have escape sequences."?

Comment: I've tried to explain a little more my issues above

Comment: "... with all of the escape sequences converted" -- converted from character to escape sequence or the other way around?

Comment: Convert from escape sequence to character

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. `"Hello \\  Bob \n Newman"` is a string literal which evaluates to a string with only one backslash and one newline character in it. There are no escape sequences in this string (unless you think "\ ", backslash-space, is an escape sequence).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are confused about the amount of escaping that occurs in your example.

When you write

```
val s1 = "Hello \n world!"
```

then the escape is already interpreted by the SML parser, `s1` itself will not contain any at runtime. You can print the string as is.

A string that actually contains escapes *at runtime* would e.g. be

```
val s2 = "Hello \\n world!"
```

because here the SML parser interprets `\\` into a (single) slash. You can then convert `s2` at runtime using `String.fromString`, yielding the same string as `s1`.

So back to your example, `esc` denotes the runtime string

```
Hello \  Bob 
 Newman
```

with a slash followed by a space. That is not a valid escape sequence, and so `String.fromString` only converts the string up to that "parsing" error (that is the semantics of all `fromString` functions in SML -- if you use the underlying `scan` functions directly, you also get back the rest string).

Answer (score 1):

I just fired PolyML and tried the following:

```
Poly/ML 5.5.0 Release
> val a = "Hello \\ Bob \n Newman";
val a = "Hello \\ Bob \n Newman": string
> print a;
Hello \ Bob 
 Newmanval it = (): unit
> print (String.toString a);
Hello \\ Bob \n Newmanval it = (): unit
>
```

In other words, escape sequences are already interpreted by default as the characters they represent, and you have to use `String.toString` to "unescape" special characters (get a string containing the original escape sequences). Or, even better, you can encode the escape sequences using escape sequences themselves, as Andreas showed.

Comment: I've added clarification to my question.  Thanks for your help